# UITabBar standard icons location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I want to get standard xcode icons for UITabBar. Does anybody know where location of this icons? Or give link to same, FREE and Retina display icons please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) to get the icons, but note that those belong to apple and you would deploy them as part of "your" application..

Comment: xcode also belongs to apple, but i'm using it to create my application :)

Thanks, I found them.

Comment: but you don't put Xcode functionality inside your app.. just be aware that apple might consider this to be a copyright infringement. they allow you to use the icons via API but you want to copy and distribute these icons yourself